# How to find the First, Second, Third and Fourth Saturday in month?

Tags: t-sql

How do I find the first, second, third and fourth saturday of the month?

Ex.: I want to end up with this format...

> Blockquote

YYYY, MM, Week#1

> Blockquote

YYYY, MM, Week#2

> Blockquote

Thanks,

Comment: Use a preloaded calendar table, or a numbers table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, using a stacked cte to create an inline tally table, with another cte on top of that to generate the months calendar.
Please note that you can change the `GETDATE()` in the first row code to any date you want (even if it's in the middle of the month) and the code will produce all the Saturdays in that month.

```
-- Get the current month's start date
DECLARE @MonthStart datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())), 0)

;WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)

-- gets all the dates in the current month
,CurrentMonth AS (SELECT TOP (32) dateadd(day, n-1, @MonthStart) As TheDate
                  FROM Tally
                  WHERE MONTH(dateadd(day, n-1, @MonthStart)) = MONTH(@MonthStart)
                  ORDER BY n)

-- gets all the Saturday dates of the current month                    
SELECT TheDate, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TheDate)
FROM CurrentMonth
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, TheDate) = 7 -- Depending on server settings!
```

If you already have a numbers table, you can use it instead of the stacked cte. If you don't know what is a numbers table and why you should have one, read [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) by Jeff Moden

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not depend on `Datefirst` setting.

```
declare @d datetime = getdate();

select
    dateadd(dd, n, firstSaturday)
from (
    select 
        firstSaturday = dateadd(day, 7-(@@datefirst+datepart(weekday, dateadd(day,-1, convert(char(6),@d,112)+'01')))%7, dateadd(day,-1, convert(char(6),@d,112)+'01'))
    ) t
    cross apply (values (0), (7), (14), (21)) q(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE @MonthId INT = 5
DECLARE @FirstDayOfTheMonth DATE = CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), RIGHT(CONCAT('00', @MonthId),2), '01')
DECLARE @SaturdayId INT = 6 

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, @SaturdayId + WK.ID - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @FirstDayOfTheMonth), @FirstDayOfTheMonth)
FROM ( VALUES(0),(7),(14),(21),(28)) AS WK(ID)
WHERE 
    MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, @SaturdayId + WK.ID- DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @FirstDayOfTheMonth),@FirstDayOfTheMonth)) = @MonthId
```